# How to make MediaBrowserService accessible from Android Auto?

Tags: java, android, android-auto

I have implemented a `MusicPlayerService` by following the official guide from the Android Developers site. At multiple places, I have found the information that this should be enough to make my app ready for Android Auto.

But if I open that (just the phone interface because I don't have a compatible car at the moment), the list of music providers just contains Google Music and the already installed VLC media player. To verify I also downloaded, compiled and installed the [Universal Music Player example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-UniversalMusicPlayer), which isn't showing up either.

Do I have to enable something or even upload the app to Google Play first?

**EDIT:** I now tested it with the [Desktop Head Unit](https://developer.android.com/training/auto/testing/index.html) and it works. Afterwards the service is also visible on the phone interface. But this is not the expected behavior, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only apps installed through Google Play will be shown in Android Auto. If you want to test your app with the phone interface, you'll need to enable developer mode and the 'unknown sources' option in the developer settings.

https://developer.android.com/training/auto/testing/index.html#phone